# What is the default initial learningrate in neuralnet for rprop in r?

Tags: r, neural-network

What is the default initial learningrate in neural net if I choose rprop to be the algorithm in r?

Answer (score 0):

The `rprop` algorithm implemented in `neuralnet` appears to use the same defaults as those from the [paper](http://www.inf.fu-berlin.de/lehre/WS06/Musterererkennung/Paper/rprop.pdf) on Rprop. (See `neuralnet:::varify.variables` for more details.) Under section C in the paper,

> When learning starts, all update-values are set to an initial value delta_0. Since delta_0 directly determines the size of the first weight step, it should be chosen according to the initial values of the weights themselves, for example delta_0=0.1 (default setting). The choice of this value is rather uncritical, for it is adapted as learning proceeds.

Also, from the internal function `neuralnet:::rprop` which utilizies the Rprop algorithm, we see the line

```
learningrate <- as.vector(matrix(0.1, nrow = 1, ncol = length.unlist))
```

So the default learning rate using `rprop` is 0.1.